# RevenueCat multiple subscription buttons in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, revenuecat

I followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0H2SdKf4ot0 which was immensely helpful in helping me get RC setup in my SwiftUI app. I was able to get purchasing working for a single subscription using a button:

```
VStack {
                    Button(action: {
                        Purchases.shared.offerings { offerings, error in
                            if let packages = offerings?.current?.availablePackages {
                                Purchases.shared.purchasePackage(packages.first!, { transaction, purchaserInfo, error, userCancelled in
                                    print("TRANSACTION: \(transaction)")
                                    print("PURCHASER INFO: \(purchaserInfo)")
                                    print("USER CANCELED: \(userCancelled)")

                                    if purchaserInfo?.entitlements["Pro"]?.isActive == true {
                                    }
                                })
                            }
                        }

                    }, label: {
                        Text("1 month")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .frame(maxWidth: 280)
                    })

                }
```

The challenge I’m facing now is that I have 3 purchase options for my one Entitlement : monthly sub, annual sub, and lifetime. These are all ready configured in App Store Connect and on RC.

Since this example uses `packages.first` (and correctly grabs the monthly sub) how do I configure my yearly and lifetime buttons? There’s no `packages.second` or `packages.third`

Appreciate any insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the widely used answer to this is just using a `ForEach` loop. Thanks to Josh over at RC Forums! https://community.revenuecat.com/general-questions-7/multiple-subscription-buttons-swiftui-1290?postid=3962#post3962

```
struct MyView: View {

  @State private var packages = [Purchases.Package]()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ForEach(packages, id: \.self) { package in
        Button {
          // Purchase package
        } label: {
          Text(package.localizedPriceString)
        }
      }
    }.onAppear {
      Purchases.shared.offerings { (offerings, error) in
        if let offering = offerings?.current {
          packages = offering.availablePackages
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```